# Comparison between Hibernate and Cayenne

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, apache-cayenne

Someone please help me in choosing whether to use Hibernate or Cayenne?

Which is more suitable to handle large databases?

Answer (score 14):

I used both, but if I was in charge (and not my boss :) ) I would prefer Cayenne.

Cayenne has a very nice CayenneModeler, so you don't have to write any mapping code - just click your way an entire project in a few minutes.

If you have performance sensitive areas in you project, Cayenne has something called SQLTemplate - a very very efficient solution.

And last but not least, as a newbie or as a simple user, you get very fast very good solutions to your questions - as opposed to the Hibernate forums - just look how many questions are unanswered there.

Comment: Definitely Cayenne, because of the good Modeler, and also because of the fantastic support: nn the Hibernate forums, many of the newbie questions  are not answered, or users are restricted to very few allowed questions.

Comment: One caveat with Cayenne is that it's not good at handling databases without primary keys or non integer primary keys.  There are hacks for hibernate to use composite primary keys to work around this issue.  I've also had issues with Cayenne caching stale data, but still prefer Cayenne for most projects.

Answer (score 6):

### [Bill Dudney](http://www.theserverside.com/tt/blogs/showblog.tss?id=CayenneAndHibernate) -

> Overall in my limited expierence
>   Cayenne is a robust and fun framework
>   to develop with. There are lots of
>   cool features and if you know
>   Hibernate its a small leap to grok
>   Cayenne. Cayenne seems to have a
>   vibrant community of users and the
>   list was very friendly and answered my
>   simpleton questions quickly and
>   without trying to make me feel stupid.
>   Cayenne seems to be a bit less mature
>   than Hibernate in a few areas, for
>   example, the distributed caching is
>   new in version 1.1. In general though
>   Cayenne is a great framework and I
>   would definitely recommend that you
>   take a look at it when you start your
>   next project that requires an ORM
>   framework.

Comment: Thanks bill. I will check out cayenne to see how it behaves with the large DB.

Answer (score -1):

This discussion on relative strengths or Hibernate vs. Toplink offers few important point an which features to look when evaluating:

http://programming.itags.org/development-tools/120839/